# listbox is not enabled using the below conditon

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

In my operation i want to edit an employee list. In this time am using the below statement to disable listbox.

```
  this.lstbox.Attributes.Add("Disabled", "");
```

After the updation am using the below code to enable list box .

```
  this.lstbox.Attributes.Add("enabled", "");
```

First condition is working properly but second one does not return any error and list box not enabled..

Please help me to fix this..

Comment: The `disabled` and `readonly` attributes are, by definition, always on when present, regardless of the value assigned to them. So, as Paolo mentions below, you must remove the attribute to re-enable the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should rather remove the "Disabled" attribute:

```
lstbox.Attributes.Remove("Disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

without ever touching asp.net but after looking at: "[list box enabled example](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/how-to-enable-disable-listbox.html)"

can't you just write:

```
lstbox.Enabled = true;
lstbox.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: i got the solution am using "this.lstbox.Attributes.Remove("disabled");". This command is working fine..

Comment: I voted for this one :) I think it's better to use the provided "Enabled" property (of which I was not aware) than fiddling with the attributes directly.